# JQuery fadeOut() and fadeIn() functions doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna make a floating text on a page, changing between the quotes on the quotes array. And adding some effect during this change.

I have this Html code:

```
<body onLoad="frase1();">
    <h1 id="textslide" class="frase-topo"></h1>
</body>
```

And this JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    var quotes = [
        "Aqui vai uma frase bem bonita",
        "E aqui também vai uma frase bem bonita"
    ];
    var i = 0;

    setInterval(function () {

        $('#textslide').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('#textslide').html(quotes[i]);
            $('#textslide').fadeIn('slow');
        });

        if (i === quotes.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }, 4000);

</script>
```

The quotes are changing.
But it's not showing the fade effect when the quotes are changing. Someone can help?

Comment: your script works. Looks this example: http://jsfiddle.net/z24c5pyo/, some error in console?

Comment: You did of course close the `h1` tag ?

Comment: Yes, i have closed the <h1>!

Comment: The site is this: http://salvatorianas.net.br/site/jsav/

Comment: @Ronaldo, have you checked that some other part of your code is not setting `$.fx.off` to `true`?

Comment: checking your website, i can tell that the property for transition of your class `frase-topo`, is interfering with the jquery function. Remove it.  `transition: all 1s;`

Comment: Yup! Thank Holybreath! I put this to the test, and I forgot to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, wrap your function in a `$(document).ready()` function to ensure that the DOM is loaded before running your code.

Second, change your `setInterval` to a `setTimeout`.  This makes the code wait until the previous function is complete before running it again.  This should give you the results that you are wanting.  See the snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var quotes = [
        "Aqui vai uma frase bem bonita",
        "E aqui também vai uma frase bem bonita"
    ];
    var i = 0;
    var timeOut = function () {
        $('#textslide').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('#textslide').html(quotes[i]);
            $('#textslide').fadeIn('slow');
            if (i === quotes.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            else {
                i++;
            }
            window.setTimeout(function () { timeOut(); }, 4000);
        });
    };
    timeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <h1 id="textslide" class="frase-topo"></h1>
</body>
```

Comment: @RonaldoScotti - is the snippet above working for you?  If so, then there's something else on your site that's stopping it from working.

Comment: No, its showing me this:

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: @RonaldoScotti - I'm not sure what you're getting a 500 - Internal Server Error on.  Did you hit `Run code snippet` in the answer?  Is it working for you?

Comment: @RonaldoScotti - what browser are you using?